# Count number of even leaves in a Binary Number Tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

Okay so for this assignment I have to define a recursive function that takes a binary number tree and returns the number of leaves that have even numbers on them. The function I have to far looks like this:

```
def count_even_leaves(bnt):
    """bnt -> number"""
    evens = []
    if not isinstance(bnt,tuple):
        return bnt
    else:
        if count_even_leaves(bnt[0]) % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(count_even_leaves(bnt[0]))
        elif count_even_leaves(bnt[1]) % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(count_even_leaves(bnt[1]))
    return len(evens)
```

This seems to me like it should work, but it's not returning the answers that I would expect.

Comment: Are you sure you want to append the value of `count_even_leaves(bnt[0/1])`? You are misusing `evens` in that case by returning its length at the end. Don't you think it would be better to use a number and *add* to it from the left and right trees instead? Or, if you really want to gather a list of the evens, and return their length, don't append the count of even numbers, instead, append a *list* of even numbers. By the way, you don't account for any leaf node being even. Basically, you have no base case and you're not even checking the value of the leafs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def count_even_leaves(bnt):
    if not isinstance(bnt,tuple):
        return (bnt+1)%2
    evens = count_even_leaves(bnt[0])
    evens += count_even_leaves(bnt[1])
    return evens
```

Is this what you're looking for? I'm assuming all leaves are just ints and a node which is not a leave is a tuple/array containing the left and right child in [0] and [1].

Comment: `return bnt%2` will give 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers

Comment: This still doesn't always work though. If I input say `(25,((10,4),(12,11)))` as my binary number tree, it returns `2` instead of `3` like the assignment says it should.

Comment: Ah never mind with that edit it totally works. Awesome thank you!